# Access Denied when using WinJS promise

Tags: windows, winjs, windows-10, winjs-promise

I am trying to get dial device from an ID, but when I use `.done()` or `.then()` on `.fromIdAsync()` as given in the api [DialDevice.FromIdAsync | fromIdAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.dialprotocol.dialdevice.fromidasync.aspx). I am getting access denied error and app is getting closed

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you've declared the extensibility point of type windows.dialProtocal in appxmanifest using something like:

```
   <Extensions> 
     <uap:Extension Category="windows.dialProtocol"> 
       <uap:DialProtocol Name="your app's DIAL name" /> 
     </uap:Extension> 
   </Extensions>
```

If you still encounter exception, I think that may indicate DIAL is not supported. The [c# officle sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/AdvancedCasting) is not a code reference for js developer, but should be a good testing project to verify if it works in c# project.

Comment: Is this code snippet to create a dial app? I need something like searching chromecast device and stream to it. @Alan Yao - MSFT